# How to divide contents of one column by different values, conditional on contents of a second column?

Tags: r

I've got a data frame that looks like something along these lines:

```
Day        Salesperson        Value
====      ============        =====
Monday       John              40
Monday       Sarah             50
Tuesday      John              60
Tuesday      Sarah             30
Wednesday    John              50
Wednesday    Sarah             40
```

I want to divide the value for each salesperson by the number of times that each of the days of the week has occurred. So: There have been 3 Monday, 3 Tuesdays, and 2 Wednesdays — I don't have this information digitally, but can create a vector along the lines of

```
c(3, 3, 2)
```

How can I conditionally divide the **Value** column based on the number of times each day occurs?

I've found an inelegant solution, which entails copying the **Day** column to a **temp** column, replacing each of the names of the week in the new column with the number of times each day occurs using

```
df$temp <- sub("Monday, 3, df$temp)
```

but doing this seems kinda clunky. Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: Generally a good idea to show the desired output so we can check whether answers work for you.

Comment: @Frank my bad, you're right. Your answer below pretty much nailed it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your auxiliary data is in another data.frame:

```
        Day N_Day
1    Monday     3
2   Tuesday     3
3 Wednesday     2
```

The simplest way would be to merge:

```
DF_new        <- merge(DF, DF2, by="Day")
DF_new$newcol <- DF_new$Value / DF_new$N_Day
```

which gives

```
        Day Salesperson Value N_Day   newcol
1    Monday        John    40     3 13.33333
2    Monday       Sarah    50     3 16.66667
3   Tuesday        John    60     3 20.00000
4   Tuesday       Sarah    30     3 10.00000
5 Wednesday        John    50     2 25.00000
6 Wednesday       Sarah    40     2 20.00000
```

The mergeless shortcut is

```
DF$newcol <- DF$Value / DF2$N_Day[match(DF$Day, DF2$Day)]
```

---

**Data:**

```
DF <- structure(list(Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
c("Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), Salesperson = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("John", "Sarah"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(40L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 50L, 40L)), .Names = c("Day", 
"Salesperson", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

DF2 <- structure(list(Day = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday"), class = "factor"), N_Day = c(3, 3, 2)), .Names = c("Day", 
"N_Day"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just before I pressed the button you posted the same answer :P. You can easily make the auxiliary data with `data.frame(table(df$Day))`.

Comment: @LyzandeR The OP says the auxiliary data is exogenous (dunno from where), not derived.

Comment: Ahhh fair enough. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library `dplyr` to merge your data frame with the frequency of each day.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Day=c("Monday","Monday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"),
  Salesperson=c("John","Sarah","John","Sarah","John","Sarah"),
  Value=c(40,50,60,30,50,40), stringsAsFactors=F)

aux <- data.frame(
  Day=c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"),
  freq=c(3,3,2)
)

output <- df %>% left_join(aux, by="Day") %>% mutate(Value2=Value/n)
```

To create this auxiliary table with the count of days that appear in your original data instead of doing it manually. You could use:

```
aux <- df %>% group_by(Day) %>% summarise(n=n())

> output
        Day Salesperson Value n Value2
1    Monday        John    40 2     20
2    Monday       Sarah    50 2     25
3   Tuesday        John    60 2     30
4   Tuesday       Sarah    30 2     15
5 Wednesday        John    50 2     25
6 Wednesday       Sarah    40 2     20
```

If you want to substitute the actual `value`column, then use `mutate(Value=Value/n)` and to remove the additional columns, you can add a `select(-n)`

```
output <- df %>% left_join(aux, by="Day") %>% mutate(Value=Value/n) %>% select(-n)
```